# How to enable GPS automatically

Tags: android

I am using this code will get Security exception.

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
}
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
}
}
```

How to fix problem automatic enable GPS.

Comment: [Android device GPS on/off programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22529296/3330969)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. So is there any other way to do GPS on\off?

Comment: Point # 4 is your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For The security purpose Google developer has block above both methods which were previously working fine. 
So you cant enable GPS programatically

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. So is there any other way to do GPS on\off?

Comment: Sorry buddy there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

> Well Now There is no Way/work-around To Enable Gps Progmatically.

what you can do is to Ask From the user to open the gps, if gps is not enabled.

first check if gps is enabled or not

```
public boolean check_Gps(Context context) {
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return statusOfGPS;
}
```

and then open gps Actvity if not enabled.

```
if (!check_Gps(Your_Activity_Name.this)) {

   open_Gps_Activity(Your_Activity_Name.this);


 }

  public void open_Gps_Activity(Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and you can also show a toast to tell the user that if you will not turn on the gps your app will not work properly.