# Is there any way turn off android sensers programmaticaly?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to turn off sensors like GPS programaticaly. how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Enable GPS

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Disable GPS

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528984/android-device-gps-on-off-programatically#22529296) suggests that this doesn't work in modern Android versions. I guess nowadays the user's action is needed to change the GPS state.

Comment: Thank you dear..Is it possible to turn off other sensors also?

Comment: yes it is possible to turn off like wifi,bluetooth,phone screen,gps

Comment: @lakshithamadusanka for wifi 'WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);'                                                          you have to add permission in manifast     **    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission> **

Comment: @lakshithamadusanka for bluetooth     ******************** public static boolean setBluetooth(boolean enable) {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    if (enable && !isEnabled) {
        return bluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
    }
    else if(!enable && isEnabled) {
        return bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
    return true;
}***********************permissions are <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>