# Exception while turning on GPS

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**This is the error in logcat:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: com.example.satyajittarafdar.gps_on_automatic, PID: 20469
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.satyajittarafdar.gps_on_automatic/com.example.satyajittarafdar.gps_on_automatic.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send
>   broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=20469,
>   uid=10240
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed
>   to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=20469,
>   uid=10240
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3128)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:767)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:396)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.example.satyajittarafdar.gps_on_automatic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2382)
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Answer (score 1):

This is not available as public API, and you cannot change GPS  state programmatically from Android 4.4 and above. you have prepare intent and redirect user to settings.

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

here are some references:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529296/3758024

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20236331/3758024

Comment: But while using default Google Map,if ur GPS is off,then it will turn ON automatically showing only a alert dialogue msg...it will not take to the settings to make it ON

Comment: This is the code to ON gps manually and its working perfectly Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); startActivity(myIntent); but I dont want to make it ON through settings. If any code is there,help me. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the gps state programmaticly since android version 4.4.

Good explanation why: [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528984/android-device-gps-on-off-programatically)

What you should so is using intent to send the user to the phoen setting and request him to enable it manually.

Comment: But while using default Google Map,if ur GPS is off,then it will turn ON automatically showing only a alert dialogue msg...it will not take to the settings to make it ON.

Comment: This is the code to ON gps manually and its working perfectly
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

but I dont want to make it ON through settings.

If any code is there,help me.
Thanx in advance